# Azure Application Gateway ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT From Web Browser

Tags: azure, nginx, nginx-config

I have one of the strangest issues I have seen in a long time when using the Azure Application Gateway and myself and my team are stumped and need some tips on how to troubleshoot the issue.

Enter https://example.com - web page server properly

Enter http://example.com - redirected to https://example.com web page served properly.

The current behavior is this when the user has *never* reached our site before:

Enter example.com (no http|https) receive ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Enter example.com/any-valid-path - receive ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

We are serving NGINX from a Docker container behind a WAF with the AppGateway and using a port 80 listener to redirect to 443.

Once again, when you use the protocol in the browser it works properly, this only happens when you directly type the url directly into the browser without the protocol attached.

This has been observed in Chrome and Edge. The only way I can test this is to removed all history and cache of our site in my browser and effectively reset chrome. All DNS entries are correct and can reach the gateway without fail. There is something happening between the negotiation of the url and getting it to the proper app service.

Some more information:

We use a "basic" listener to redirect from port 80 to port 443? Should we be using a multi-site instead with a hostname?

Should I be focusing on an NGINX issue with config?

Comment: Should not need a multi-site listener.  Is there authentication and redirect associated with the site? i.e. is traffic getting redirected for login and then back in again?  Also what happens when you update your local host file to manual point your DNS entry to the IP of the application Gateway?

Comment: Thanks for the help! We do not have any auth getting in the way, it is open to the public. I will point my DNS over in my local host file - good suggestion, I'll report back ASAP.